# Share point visual webpart with ajax modal popup

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, visual-web-part, jquery-ui

I am trying to update the text area displayed in the Ajax modal popup. I am updating the Text area with sharepoint list multiline text field. My spservices is wriiting the data correctly. But when i try to appened the Text area it is unable to show the same.

I am trying to append the data on button click.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function GetListData() 
    {
        var method = "GetListItems";
        var list = "WOGDates";
        var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='WOGLicense' />" +
                            "</ViewFields>";

        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Neq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" +
                            "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";
        $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false,
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
            CAMLQuery: query,
            //this basically means "do the following code when the call is complete"
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                    var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                    var WOGLicensetext = $($(this).attr("ows_WOGLicense")).text();
                    AppenedData(name, WOGLicensetext);
                });
            }
        });
        function AppenedData(name, WOGLicensetext) 
        {

            $("textarea#idTxtArGenHtml").append(result.WOGLicensetext);

        }

    }


</script>






<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_noact" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="282px" CssClass="style4"></asp:Label>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvdetails" DataKeyNames="EventID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="502px">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDate" HeaderText="Start Time" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="End Time" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="EventID_HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("EventID")%>' />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" Width="80" Height="25" OnClick="SignUp_Click" OnClientClick="GetListData()"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Drag="true" DropShadow="true">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>


 <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server"  BackColor="LightGray" Height="500px" Width="800px" Style="display: none">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">         
            <tr>
                <td align="center" 
                    style="background-color: #79A2E2; width: 350px; height: 80%;">
                    <samp>
                        <b style="color: #000000; font-size:11pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                            just a test
                            <br />                            
                            this date has to be finished
                            <br />
                           santosh </b>
                    </samp>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <span><textarea  name="nTxtArGenHtml" id="idTxtArGenHtml" width='100%' cols="8" rows="8"></textarea></span>
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="True" Width="80%" Height="300px">
                    </asp:TextBox>--%>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="PnlPopup_Hiddenfeild" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Agree" runat="server" Text="I have read and agree to the above terms"
                        CommandName="SignUp" OnClick="btnAgree_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel I Do Not Agree" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two strings (`name` and `WOGLicensetext`) to your `AppendData` function, yet in the function you are trying to access a `result` object, which probably doesn't exist in that scope.

So you should change

```
$("textarea#idTxtArGenHtml").append(result.WOGLicensetext);
```

to

```
$("textarea#idTxtArGenHtml").append(WOGLicensetext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$("textarea#idTxtArGenHtml").html(result.WOGLicensetext);
```

or

```
$("textarea#ExampleMessage").val(result.exampleMessage)
```

depend on if you want to display it as html tags or plain text.